# how to change the background color of a listview when clicked once and when clicked again i need to change the background color without using selector

Tags: android

how to change the background color of a listview when clicked once and when clicked again i need to change the background color without using selector.I have worked on changing the background when i select each item.but when i click again on the item i need to change the background color as red.how can i give the condition.i will post my code here.please give suggestions.please help...

public class ProvierActivity extends Activity {

```
private String text[] = { "BroadStripe-Cable (Seattle)",
        "BroadStripe-Digital (Seattle)", "BroadStripe-Cable (Seattle)",
        "Comcast king county south)", "BroadStripe-Cable (Seattle)",
        "Comcast king county south", "BroadStripe-Digital (Seattle)",
        "BroadStripe-Digital (Seattle)", "BroadStripe-Cable (Seattle)",
        "Comcast king county south" };

ImageView icon;
public static int selectedRow;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    final ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview_id);

    list.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list,
            R.id.title, text));
    list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View view,
                int position, long arg3) {

            for (int i = 0; i < adapter.getChildCount(); i++) {
                if (i == position) {

                    adapter.getChildAt(i).setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);

                } else {
                    adapter.getChildAt(i).setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);

                }

            }

        }

    });
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this edited code.

```
public static int selectedRow;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */

private int prePos=-1;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    final ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview_id);

    list.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list,
            R.id.title, text));
    list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View view,
                int position, long arg3) {

            for (int i = 0; i < adapter.getChildCount(); i++) {
                if (i == position) {   

                    if(position!=prePos){   
                       adapter.getChildAt(i).setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);

                      prePos=position;

                    }else{
                        adapter.getChildAt(i).setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
                          prePos=-1;
                        }

                   }else{

                      adapter.getChildAt(i).setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);

                   }

                }


        }

    });
}

}
```

this will help you.

Comment: thanks for the help.its working.but i want if one is selected and when we select another item the previous one should be black.that is the item which i select only should change color.can u pls help in that also.

Comment: can you explain again clearly? i think your code is matching your requirements.

Comment: Yeah I have posted my code before.That is working correctly.that is when i select one item the color changes and when i select another item the color changes only for the selected item and all other items have black color background.but after introducing flag my need is not working.

Comment: I want 2 things in the same condition.1.the background has to change only for selected items and the previous selected items background should change to black.

Comment: 2. is when i double click the selected item, it should change to black again.how can i achievw both these conditions.

Comment: where you are introducing and using flag?

Comment: as you have posted the edited code i used the same..its working but my 1st condition is not satisfied.

Comment: now use the edited answer. if not satisfied your requirements ask me.

Comment: yeah its working .thanks.but again i have a problem.when i click twice the second item get selected and change to blue.I want it in a single click the selected item should change to blue.thanks.thanks u so much for sparing your time.

Comment: thanks, thank u so much.I was trying this for a long time.thanks for sparing time with me

Comment: again the problem came.when i click one item color changes and when i click the same item color becomes black and when i again click the same item it is not changing to blue.can u pls again help me in that?